# Mocking a method with conditional arguments using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a class that I am unit testing, to verify a specific exception condition is handled gracefully.  To this end, I mock the method that is called internally to throw the exception.

my mocking setup looks like this:

```
fr.CallBase = true;
fr.Setup(m => m.PutFile(It.IsAny<IFileConnection>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Throws(new System.IO.IOException("Test Exception", new System.Net.Sockets.SocketException()));
```

this does exactly what I want it to do.

Now, however, I want to test continuity by only throwing an exception for a specific value.  I thought it should look like this:

```
fr.Setup(m => m.PutFile(It.IsAny<IFileConnection>(), It.Is<string>(a => a == "foo2.txt"), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Throws(new System.IO.IOException("Test Exception", new System.Net.Sockets.SocketException()));
```

...but this doesn't seem to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Per request, the entire test:

```
[Test]
public void ManualRouteInterruptedInDownloadContinuesOn()
{
    var firstRoute = this.UnitOfWork.GetFirstRoute();
    Route r = this.UnitOfWork.GetRouteByID(firstRoute.RouteID);
    r.RegExMatch = "^foo\\d.txt$";
    r.Manual = true;
    r.NotifyOfNewFiles = "me@company.com";
    this.UnitOfWork.Save();

    var fr = new Mock<ManualRouting>(r.RouteID);
    fr.CallBase = true;
    fr.Setup(m => m.GetFile(It.IsAny<IFileConnection>(), It.Is<string>(a => a == "foo2.txt"), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Throws(new System.IO.IOException("Test Exception", new System.Net.Sockets.SocketException()));

    fr.Object.ExecuteRoute(firstRoute.RouteID);
    Assert.IsTrue(fr.Object.Errors.Count == 1);
    Assert.IsTrue(fr.Object.Matches.Count == 3);
}
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, can you post the code of the entire test case?

Comment: Can you share the function call that you are trying to mock ?

Comment: @BishopRook, I added the test.

Comment: Where is the comment from the guy that suggested using `Equals()`?  That worked.

Comment: Code you posted works, the problem must lie in the parts we cannot see.

Comment: @jimmy_keen: Didn't work for me.  I changed the `It.Is<string>(a => a == "foo2.txt")` to `It.Is<string>(a => Equals(a, "foo2.txt"))` as per a suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was someone who suggested in comments that I should try

```
It.Is<string>(a => Equals(a, "foo2.txt"))
```

He cited some oddness with generics.  I don't know if it had anything to do with generics, but this change did in fact work.  Since the poster deleted his comment, I am making the answer in his stead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
m.PutFile(It.IsAny<IFileConnection>(), "foo2.txt")
```

should work

Comment: That was the first thing I tried; it didn't throw an exception, but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

How do the internals of `fr` ever know to call `GetFile` with `foo2.txt` as the file name?  It seems like you're setting up your test specification broadly (`^foo\\d.txt$`) but your mock narrowly (`foo2.txt`), shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: in the `[Setup]` for all test cases in the fixture, I create `foo1.txt`, `foo2.txt`, and `foo3.txt` that I use, and subsequently destroy the files in the `[Teardown]` method.  I want the "middle" file to fail to make sure  it's handled gracefully.